# ¿Cómo dibujar borde a capa de puntos con tmap?

Tags: r

Estoy aprendiendo a usar tmap en R. Quiero hacer un mapa de puntos y quisiera que los puntos tengan un borde para diferenciar mejor. ¿Es posible dibujar el borde ?

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola Tamara, sí puedes con los parámetros gráficos. Aunque, por lo que comentas, quizás aplicar un buffer para obtener vectores circulares puede ser una opción que te ayude a la visualización